# LUIS MS Bot framework - eu.luis.ai certificate expired?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I've been working with the European URL for LUIS. Since yesterday I'm getting security warnings.

Is anyone facing the same issue? even if I accept the warning and try to log in, after putting my credentials it just go back to the home page.

[image: luis eu issue]

Comment: _"I'm getting security warnings."_ on what page? Wildcard cert looks valid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNOWP.png

Comment: I'm trying to work with the European server https://eu.luis.ai/home

Comment: I also got certificate issues, but when trying to login from eu.luis.ai/home page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Xa4.png

Comment: Yeah, they've messed their cert up, bad wildcard. You should report it to them. Some browsers might let you accept it anyway..

Answer (score 0):

At 18:10 (UTC+01) I was able to log in and continue my developments. It seems MS already addressed the issue.